# Asp.Net Core Authorization Policy

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I stumbled over an article of the discussion over the new Asp.Net Core authorization policy which was introduced. Many people criticized the feature but I found it useful to me when I was battling with an authorization issue in my web API.

My Web App had two sections. An API and a web App in the same project. It also had two `DbContext`, `DbContext1` and `DbContext2`; therefore two set of Identity users. As per two users, one user had to authenticate from the other `DbContext1` to access the other `DbContex2`. And also, `DbContext2` was initialized by `DbContext1`. I had made authorization working properly with the Web App which was using cookie authentication but then authorization was not working for the API.
I designed my API controllers with the authorize attribute `[Authorize(Roles="AdminDb2,SupervisorDb2")]`
but then nothing worked. There was a problem. My default Identity store was using `DbContext1` for its identity store which means users of `DbContext2` cannot be authorized. Yes the fact that I used `JWT Authentication` also nothing worked. Also I had to go to my `startup` file and do the following

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddIdentity<Db1User, Db1Role>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DbContext1>()
                .AddRoleManager<Db1RoleManager>()
                .AddSignInManager<Db1SignInManager>()
                .AddUserManager<DbAuthenticationManager>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
                .AddDefaultUI(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.UIFramework.Bootstrap4);
}
```

and also added the second Identity by calling

```
services.AddIdentityCore<Db2User>()
```

Nothing worked.
After days of thinking while authorization was not working I figured out that Identity store was trying to authorize users with `DbContext1`. Okaaaay, Now I get. I now found the Policy based authorization useful.
I now did this in my `startup` file

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("SuperPolicy", pOptions =>
                {
                    pOptions.AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                    pOptions.Requirements.Add(new ApiRequirement("Admin,SuperAdmin"));
                });
}
```

Then I had to use the method which was preferred to handle the authorization like this

```
public class ApiRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
    {
        public string[] Requirements { get; }
        public ApiRequirement(params string[] requirements)
        {
            Requirements = requirements;
        }

    }

public class ApiAuthorizeHandler: AuthorizationHandler<ApiRequirement>
    {
        private readonly TokenValidator _tokenValidator;
        public ApiAuthorizeHandler(TokenValidator tokenValidator)
        {
            _tokenValidator = tokenValidator;
        }

        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, ApiRequirement requirement)
        {
            AuthorizationFilterContext filterContext = (AuthorizationFilterContext)context.Resource;
            string authToken = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
            TokenValidator validationResult = _tokenValidator.ValidateToken(authToken);
            bool result = validationResult.IsInRole(requirement.Requirements);
            if (result)
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
                context.User.AddIdentity(validationResult.ClaimsPrincipal.Identities.First());
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
            context.Fail();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

With this I needed not to write a new Authorization filter

then I designed my controllers with the usual Authorize filters

```
[Authorize(Policy="SuperPolicy")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{

}
```

One thing I found out with this method is that whenever you want to add roles or requirements to the attribute, you have to go to your startup file where authorization is injected and do the `options.AddPolicy().....` stuff which makes your startup file begin to look untidy. But if not that then its good on the go.
I found this out thought of sharing it, maybe it could help.

Comment: I had to change my authorization implementation to policy-based because filters don't work on SignalR Hubs. So implemented this: https://github.com/ilkerkaran/simple-claim-based-auth hope helps. Happy coding!